# What is the suggested practice for storing multiple runs of a summary writer in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I am learning to use TensorBoard and every time I launch tensorboard I get in my terminal the message:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Found more than one graph event per run. Overwriting the graph with the newest event.
```

I assume is because I've run the same model multiple times with the same name. I just want to run my model multiple times and be able to inspect what its doing using tensorflow. Is just re running:

```
tensorboard --logdir=path/to/log-directory
```

not the usual way to do it? Or what is the suggestion for doing this type of work when I want to run the same model multiple times with and explore different learning algorithms, step-sizes, initilization, etc. Is it really neccessary to set up a new log directory each time?

Answer (score 6):

When you export the model in your graph tensorflow creates a new file with the log information. So every time you run it the new information is added in the same folder.

As tensorboard cannot differenciate one model from other it shows the warning. So yes, you should use a different log folder per iteration. Indeed, some of the examples remove the log dir before running a graph.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `tf.summary.FileWriter()`, you provide TF with a directory in which it will write event files and add summaries and events to it. Each new file is consists of the name, timestamp and your machine. So when you run the writer multiple time, it creates a new file in your directory. Try it a couple of runs you will get something like this `ls -1` (I ran it 4 times):

```
events.out.tfevents.1492391591.salvadordali-laptop
events.out.tfevents.1492395088.salvadordali-laptop
events.out.tfevents.1492395117.salvadordali-laptop
events.out.tfevents.1492395120.salvadordali-laptop
```

Your warning tells you exactly the same: found many runs, will use the last one. You can ignore it because it will use the latest run (based on the timestamp).

If you do not like the warning, you can either:

- create different folders for each run (can be helpful to compare the plots or graph execution)
- remove the files after each run `rm -R logs/` (if logs is your directory)